# Returning a mysql query based off of 2 dimensional array contents

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

Let me preface this with an explanation:

I am working on a small project where I put an undetermined radius around a city in Google Maps. I have a table in a mysql database that contains all the cities and their lat and lng coordinates (which is needed to plot the circle).

For the users of this app, I have it set up so all they need to do is add the city and the state in the following format: city_st

The one string will contain all the needed cities:
$parseLocations = "sioux city_ia, alabaster_al, boise_id, atlanta_ga";

My issue is that while it works on the first item in that string, none of the others pull from the database even though it seems to me that the $sql variable I have is requesting the correct information. This runs in a loop, so I am confused as to why the first item works fine, but none of the others do.

Thanks for any assistance

```
<?PHP

$user = 'root';
$password = 'password';
$db = 'interactionDesign';
$host = 'localhost';
$port = 8889;
$conn = (mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $db));
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully." . "<p>";


// break out the string of locations
$parseLocations = "sioux city_ia, alabaster_al, boise_id, atlanta_ga";
$locations = explode(',', $parseLocations);


// break city_st into separate array values, add to 2 dim array
for ($x = 0; $x < count($locations); $x++) {
    $point[$x] = explode('_', $locations[$x]);
}


//loop through 2 dim array, echo values
for ($l_row = 0; $l_row < count($point); $l_row++) {

    for ($l_col = 0; $l_col < 2; $l_col++) {
        echo $l_row . " " . $l_col . " " . $point[$l_row][$l_col] . "<BR>";
    }



    $city = $point[$l_row][0];
    $state = $point[$l_row][1];
    $sql = "SELECT lat, lng, city, state FROM zipCodes WHERE city=\"$city\" and state_abb=\"$state\"";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    print_r($conn);
    echo "<p>";
    print_r($sql);
    echo"<BR>";

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo "<P>" . $row["city"] . ", " . $row["state"] . ": " . $row["lat"] . " " . $row["lng"] . "     <--- From Database" . "<p>";



}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the main problem is you have whitespace in your comma-separated string.

This:

```
$parseLocations = "sioux city_ia, alabaster_al, boise_id, atlanta_ga";
```

will `explode()` to this:

```
array("sioux city_ia", " alabaster_al"," boise_id", " atlanta_ga")
```

Note the space at the beginning of all but the first item in the array.

If you just do this:

```
$parseLocations = "sioux city_ia,alabaster_al,boise_id,atlanta_ga";
```

You should get the array values you expect.

Now that being said, I don't know why, if you are hardcoding the city/state values to begin with, that you wouldn't just hard code into a usable array like:

```
$locations = array(
    array('city' => 'some value', 'state' => 'some other value'),
    ...
);
```

and save yourself all the exploding and other string manipulations to get to a workable data structure.

Comment: Mike, that was it! The spacing is what was causing it to die on me. Thank you so much, I can keep my remaining hair. I wish I could upvote your answer, but my rep is too low. :( 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the user should enter all places separated with comma(,). The variable `$parseLocations` could therefore be entered by the user, if the user enters a lot of spaces(before or after the comma), you want it to work anyway.

Please try this one:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($locations); $x++) {
    $point[$x] = explode('_', trim($locations[$x]));
}
```